# Jenkins build promotion: How do I get the build id of the build I want to promote?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

It seems that, when doing a build promotion in Jenkins using the Promoted Builds Plugin, it generates a new BUILD_ID environment variable. Is there a way, or a plugin that lets you access the current BUILD_ID of the build you are trying to promote?

Basically, the functionality I need is to: Navigate to a build in Jenkins, be able to launch an ant or gradle script to promote an already built artifact that is archived under the build I'm currently in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the PROMOTED_JOB_NAME and PROMOTED_NUMBER variables to get the name and build number of the build being promoted.  These two values are only set DURING the promotion process; they are part of the jobs build.  This doesn't exactly map to BUILD_ID, but it does allow access to that build.

When I had this problem in the past, I did the following.

1. Have the original job copy certain variables (like JOB_ID) out to config style file (each line is NAME=VALUE).
2. Archive that file as part of the build.
3. At the time of the promotion, use the PROMOTED_JOB_NAME and PROMOTED_NUMBER variables to get the original build, feed the values into the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to retrieve the archived file of values, then use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) with that values file to bring the values into the promotion process.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I follow completely. At what point do the PROMOTED_NUMBER and PROMOTED_JOB_NAME get set? Also, archiving the config file under the build creates a similar issue that I had to begin with - how do I access the build? What would solve the issue for me is if the Parametarized Build could take dynamic values. If I could assign BUILD_TIME = %BUILD_ID%. Or something similar.

Comment: Updated answer: PROMOTED_* variables are created as part of the promotion process.  They are not part of the typical build of a job.

Comment: I'm doing a promotion and those variables seem to be null at promotion time. I must be missing something.

Comment: Using the latest version of Jenkins?  One way to verify; in the promotion commands, execute a Shell and run SET to see all the variables.

Comment: Ok, so I need the PROMOTED_ID not PROMOTED_NUMBER, other than that it's all good. This does the trick for me. There's no need for me set other env variables, I can just use PROMOTED_ID instead of BUILD_ID. Thanks!